# Redirect Sub-Domain and Directory with same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm need to do the following redirects
From: `http://xyz.domain.com/2012/01/sample.html`
To `http://www.domain.com/2012/01/sample.html`

and also

From: `http://www.domain.com/xyz/2012/01/sample.html`
To: `http://www.domain.com/2012/01/sample.html`

I'm pretty clueless on this, can somebody help me how to accomplish the same.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

For the first redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For the second redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(.+)$ /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm getting an internal server error. However, for the first one this worked RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @BCWebs Sorry, missed a `)` after `(\d{2}`